# Android HELP my if statement does not work

Tags: android

Hi I am making a logo quiz game and my if statement does not react to my input I made a textview and I pirnted out the input and it was yahoo (i entered yahoo in edit text and i declered if statement to check if it is yahoo)...

```
package com.example.logogame;

imports....

public class Yahoo extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

EditText et;
Button check;
TextView test;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.yahoo);

    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextAnswer);
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);
    test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

    check.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.buttonCheck:

        String content = et.getText().toString();

        //its always wrong here...
        if(content == "yahoo"){
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Correct! Good work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }else{
            test.setText(content);
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Wrong...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

        break;

    }
}
```

Comment: String comparision like content.equals("yahoo")

Comment: I'd suggest you do some practice Java exercises on Coding Bat. http://codingbat.com/java

Answer (score 1):

To compare `Strings` use `.equals()`.

So  Change

```
if(content == "yahoo"){
```

to

```
if(content.equals("yahoo")){
```

For more info see [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Used `.equals()` method for `String` comparison

```
  if(content.equals("yahoo"))
```

Answer (score 0):

.equals("String name ") use this for string comparison.